# String split from given last specific keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Below one is a full string , how to split string from "{" to "}" means need full object.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   234    0   159  100    75    584    275 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   584
{"scope":"Production","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":78,"refresh_token":"eregfgfg","access_token":"swewe23231c323"}
```

Need Result:

```
{"scope":"Production","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":78,"refresh_token":"eregfgfg","access_token":"swewe23231c323"}
```

Comment: please elaborate what you need from you question it is really difficult to understand your requirement

Comment: try `json.parse()`

Comment: _how to split string from "{" to "}"_ -> Fix the response of the server

Comment: thanks @AatifBandey Solve it

Comment: @ZahidRahman can you tick mark my answer if it helped you brother

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JSON.parse(yourobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple...

```
var yourObj = yourStr.substring(yourStr.indexof('{'), yourstring.length-1);
```

**OR**

```
var yourObj = yourStr.substring(yourStr.indexof('{'), yourStr.indexof('}'));
```

Friend this will only work if your string will exactly be same like you written above.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
var a  = '  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Curren Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   234    0   159  100    75    584    275 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   584 {"scope":"Production","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":78,"refresh_token":"eregfgfg","access_token":"swewe23231c323"}';

console.log((/(\{.*\})/gmi).exec(a)[0]);
```

Display : "{"scope":"Production","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":78,"refresh_token":"eregfgfg","access_token":"swewe23231c323"}"